# Maven : How to generate project's war file in two folders

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I want that when I run the mvn install, a war can be generated in the /target and an other war in the c:....tomcat 6\deploy directory.
I'm using maven2, Eclipse and m2eclipse. How to do this ??
Thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to copy your war to the tomcat deploy directory like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy file="{project.build.directory}/${project.actifactId}-${project.version}.war" tofile="<your tomcat path>/${project.actifactId}-${project.version}.war" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need to copy the war file if you try the [Maven Jetty Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin). This plugin is for running a web application directly from Maven.

Comment: I don't want to run it, it's a portlet that I want to place to the liferay-tomcat-bundle's deploy folder to be hot deployed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [cargo-maven2-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin).  Probably something like this would work:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-local</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
      <goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <container>
      <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
    </container>
    <configuration>
      <type>existing</type>
      <home>/your/tomcat/dir</home> <!-- replace as needed -->
    </configuration>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... slap that into a profile or the top-level `<build><plugins>` section and see if it works for you ...

Comment: How can I indicate the name of my .war file ? because it's not the project's name + version?

Comment: I think by default it will use the `finalName` value that you declare.  But I'm not completely sure.